# How to embed a self-contained Angular 2 application inside of an Angular 1 application

Tags: angularjs, integration, angular

*Note: I am NOT upgrading an ng1 app. I'm trying to get an ng1 and ng2 app to live side-by-side (or rather nested).*

We have roughly the following html showing how we are trying to use two frameworks on the page at once:

- Angular 1: The whole page is controlled by Angular 1. But we have used ng-non-bindable to tell the ng1 application to ignore the div in the middle of the page.
- Angular 2: Just the element in the middle of the page should be bootstrapped as Angular 2.

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head></head>
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <header>Angular 1 Stuff</header>

    <div ng-non-bindable>
      <ng2-app></ng2-app>
      <script src="bundle.js"/>
      <!-- bundle.js is the output from webpack and should bootstrap <ng2-app> -->
    </div>

    <footer>Angular 1 Stuff</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Our app works just fine when we run it on its own without trying to integrate into this ng1 application page.

When we run it after integration however, we are getting an error saying there is a conflict with the global `require` method.

- The ng1 application *is* using `requirejs`
- The ng2 bundle is the typical output from `webpack` (using `typescript-loader`)

Both requirejs and webpack use `require` but in different contexts.

**How can I resolve the conflict?**

*If you are curious why we do it this way: We are trying to bootstrap a new app on a page that also has an Angular 1 app. Our company has the global header/footer and the content of every page as a separate deployed applications. This allows teams to work on pages as stand-alone projects. One team wants to try and use Angular 2 for their new application on one of our new pages.*

Comment: it's not possible to nest two Angular 1 applications inside each other, I can only imagine that it would be challenging or impossible to try to do this with Angular 2.  That being said, angular 1 doesn't use `requirejs`, so if the conflict is with that library, then it has something to do with the way your angular 1 app was written, and nothing to do with angular itself.

Comment: Long shot from the future but have you gotten this to work?

Comment: No I never got it to work. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question itself can raise thousand of other questions.It is not at all easy to answer this question so fully because you are talking about two major MVC based architectures(Angular1 and Angular2) together.

See how to use angular2 within angular1. Successfully I can bootstrap angular2 app within angular1 app.

It is extremely important to know how you have implemented your angular1 architecture.  But if you are angular1&2 guy, you'd probably find ways on your own.

[Angular2 App within Angular1 App](http://plnkr.co/edit/YFURLDsH5m29jFUQpCs9?p=preview)

**Index.html**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
    <header>{{myValue}}</header>   //belongs to angular1

    <div ng-non-bindable>
      <my-app></my-app>

      <!-- angular 2 app bootstrapping -->
    </div>

    <footer>Angular 1 Stuff</footer>

    <script>
        var app=angular.module("app",[]);

        app.controller("appController",function($scope){
          $scope.myValue="Nyks";
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: So if you've gotten this to work I'm thinking the problem is more with how we've used requirejs and how our Angular 2 output also is access the global require function.

Comment: I don't understand why you are emphasizing on requirejs. I believe your A1 is used require but what it has to do with A2? Requirejs has nothing to do with angular2.

Comment: Because my original ng1 app uses requirejs and my new ng2 app uses webpack/typescript for bundling the JS. Both requirejs and the outputted bundle depend on a global `require' function, but they use the function differently so it conflicts.