# Embedding Angular 1.x app inside an angular 2.0 app

Tags: html, angularjs

The question is on the same lines as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802717/how-to-embed-a-self-contained-angular-2-application-inside-of-an-angular-1-appli), however the other way around.

I want to embed an Angular 1.x app inside an Angular 2 app. More specifically [this](https://github.com/Netflix/vector) app. I understand that there are ways to upgrade elements individually, however this being a large project, I simply want to embed this in one of my tabs on the Angular 2 app.

I tried a very naive approach where I copied the `dist` folder in one of my components and I am trying to use the same `index.html` with 
`<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-view="">
</div></div>`

Now I am trying to load all the minifed javascript (which includes angular 1.x library as well as some app specific javascript files and css) into my main angular 2 app in its own `index.html` . Then I load the index.html from the `dist` directory through my component. The problem seems that Angular 1 library doesnt seem to load.

I have a few questions;

1. Would it help if the libraries(js) files are loaded as ts. I assume that it is possible to load Angular 1 and 2 libraries simultaneously.
2. If it would, is there an easy way to get the `js` files converted to `.ts` files.

## EDIT

I got this to work by using the `angular.boostrap` call as shown below.
Following is my code snippet for my component

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

    declare var angular:any;
    @Component({
        selector: 'server-monitor',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/server-monitor/dist/index.html',
        styleUrls: ['app/components/server-monitor/dist/styles/vendor-c0a35f80.css',
            'app/components/server-monitor/dist/styles/main-0c4cc0e5.css',
            ],
    })
    export class ServerMonitorComponent  implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{

ngOnInit(){
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    }
}
```

However, now I have run into a different problem. The original [project](https://github.com/Netflix/vector) makes a lot of http calls very frequently(2 sec by default) to get live stats about the system.

When I run this embedded into my app, I can see the calls are made but my page keeps refreshing and doesn't show anything on the graph. I understand I have to modify something where it makes the `http` calls, but no sure where.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above edit, I modified [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) in the original app and it seems to work just fine